How to use average value in geom_line?
I am struggling to make a continuous line graph with bar plot.
I used the below code to make this graph.

Is there any way I can use geom_line with average value?
ggplot(df, aes(Date, Rain)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_line(aes(y = a + Temperature*b), size = 1.5, color = "red") + #linetype="dashed", 
  theme(axis.line.y.right = element_line(color = "red"), 
        axis.ticks.y.right = element_line(color = "red"),
        axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "red"), 
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "red"))+
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(angle = 90))+
  scale_y_continuous("Precipitation", sec.axis = sec_axis(trans=~.*3, name = "Temperature"))

Here is the link for my data file
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13kosrVt0kQsjM1dPFn4hOCp3UQ9fmBBU_KlXVRfL_J0/edit?usp=sharing

It would be easier to help you if you provide a minimal reproducible example including a snippet of your input data best shared using dput() or using some fake data or using a built-in dataset.

Maybe stat_summary(aes(y = Temperature), geom = "line", fun = mean)

You've got multiple observations per day (due to the time column).  You can either summarise the two measurements (Rain and Temperature) by Date before plotting, or use the stat_summary function from ggplot2 on the raw data.
Also, your code suggests that the x-axis contains dates stored as character. You may want to convert these to valid dates first.
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y")

summarise(df, Rain=sum(Rain), Temperature=mean(Temperature),
          .by=Date) |>
  ggplot(aes(Date, Rain, group=1)) +  # Need to specify group
     geom_line(aes(y = Temperature), linewidth = 1.5, color = "red") + 
     scale_x_date(guide = guide_axis(angle = 90),
           breaks="day") +
     scale_y_continuous("Precipitation", 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*3, name = "Temperature")) +
theme(...) +
...


Or,
ggplot(df, aes(Date, Rain)) +
  geom_col() +
  stat_summary(aes(y = Temperature), geom = "line", fun = mean,
               linewidth = 1.5, color = "red") +
  theme(...) + 
...




I got an error while trying 1st answer Error in quickdf(.data[names(cols)]) : length(rows) == 1 is not TRUE

Don't load plyr package: detach(package:plyr)

Hi, the mean using above example don't match when computed manually and using stat_summary? Any idea ?

Thank you for helping out. I fix the error.

Hi, I need a bit more help. How can I create a graph with two geom_lines: one representing the averaged low temperatures from 20:00 to 08:00 and the other representing the averaged high temperatures from 08:01 to 19:59?

Yes, please. Also, is there any possibility of creating a new column 'Month' with 06/01/2024:06/30/24 for June and so on? Thanks for your help.

I think what you want warrants a new question. Remember to provide [MRE] by using dput() and not a link to your shared drive.
